# Defining viewport and viewbox in SVG to scale shapes with physical real world units

Tags: svg, viewport, units-of-measurement, cad, viewbox

I am confused how to properly define viewport and viewbox in SVG file to convey shapes that have real world physical units.

I am mapping my AutoCAD design to a SVG file. The units in my AutoCAD file are defined in millimeters (mm). Image below shows my AutoCAD design. The orange box (16mm x 9mm) are my boundaries for visible part of the SVG file, thus anything outside the orange box will get cut off. My end application requires a PNG image that is a specific resolution, 1920x1080. (Notice how the aspect ratio is the same).

[image]

In my SVG file, all shapes (elements) are defined without units, however I know the values are in millimeters in the physical world. For example, below is an example of a circle. The radius of the circle is 0.474mm as set in the AutoCAD file.

```
<circle cx="1.22996130982" cy="2.27139057943" r="0.474" />
```

My question is, how do I properly define the viewport and viewbox in my SVG file? How do I properly define the viewport/viewbox such that the physical units in real world get scaled to fit in my desired image resolution?

I used the following method below to define my viewport/viewbox. However, this approach did not work. The resulting SVG image was a canvas of 1920x1080 however all my shapes were very tiny and it did NOT cut off the shapes desired outside the orange boundary box.

```
<svg width="1920px" height="1080px" viewbox="0 0 16mm 9mm"> 
<circle cx="1.22996130982" cy="2.27139057943" r="0.474" />
<!-- Other shapes in SVG here--> 
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: a) viewBox is case sensitive, b) it doesn't take units only numbers